# Odoo 9 home page UI change

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo-8, odoo-9

I wants to change my odoo 9 homepage(page after login):

header menus like dropdown of submenus by hiding its submenus in left bar.

Can anybody please suggest me the way to do this.?

Comment: Provide code of what you have done.

Comment: I am new to odoo, so I am not getting the procedure to make code changes